# ajax request not received by Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am trying to send a POST AJAX request to reload data in index.xhtml
But the request is never received up by the servlet.

here is my ajax call:

```
function changeStep(sub_step_id)
{
    console.log('ok');
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'X_CSRF_TOKEN':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    data:{"sub_step_id":sub_step_id},
    url:'Shop',
    success : function(data){
    console.log("sucess");
    location.href = url;
    },
        error:function(e){
        // Error
    }
});
}
```

In my servlet both doGET and doPOST method are implemented but none of them are being called when the request arrives to my server.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request,response);
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    process(request,response);
}
```

My Servlet is mapped in web.xml
here is an extract of it:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Shop</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.kino.front.homeManager</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

here the request call

[request call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4ykS.png)

Comment: What do the browser debugging tools show?

Comment: Hi stdunbar , I've added a picture of my debugging tool in my question.
As you see seems to me that POST is sent correctly but not received by my servlet.

Comment: The POST looks like it is being sent - how do you know your methods are not getting called?  I don't see any response though from the servlet side.  On the jQuery side you'll want `contentType: 'application/json'` and `dataType: 'json'` as additional parameters so that the servlet side can handle them correctly.

Comment: I know it because i put breakpoint in my doPost method and it never reached. I'll try to add contentType and dataType to header as you suggested

Comment: I updated Ajax in my question. It still does not work with header I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't mapped the url for that servlet. Add this code to your web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Shop</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/shop</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: sorry It was already present in my web.xml
So url http://localhost/mywar/shop already works but fails when it is called by ajax. Thanks for response.